# Why does tab auto-completion in Python REPL and Jupyter notebook (or ipython) for a class evaluate all its descriptors/properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to implement a Python class to facilitate easy exploration of relatively large dataset in Jupyter notebook by exposing various (some what compute intensive) filter methods as class attributes using descriptor protocol. Idea was to take advantage of lazyness of descriptor to only compute on accessing particular attribute.

Consider the following snippet:

```
import time
accessed_attr = [] # I find this easier then using basic logging for jupyter/ipython 
class MyProperty:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        accessed_attr.append(f'accessed {self.name} from {instance} at {time.asctime()}')
        setattr(instance, self.name, self.name)
        return self.name # just return string

class Dummy:
    abc=MyProperty('abc')
    bce=MyProperty('bce')
    cde=MyProperty('cde')

dummy_inst = Dummy() # instantiate the Dummy class
```

on `dummy_inst.<tab>`, I assumed Juptyer would show auto completions `abc, bce, cde` among other hidden methods and not evaluate them. Printing the logging list `accessed_attr` shows all `__get__` methods for the three descriptors were called, which is not what I expect or want.

[image: original issue]

A hacky way I figured was to deffer first access to descriptor using a counter like shown in image below, but has its own issues.
[image: silly hack]

I tried other ways using `__slots__`, modifying `__dir__` to trick the kernel, but couldn't find a way to get around the issue.

I understand there is another way using `__getattribute__`, but it still doesn't seem elegant, I am puzzled with what seemed so trivial turned out to be mystery to me. Any hints, pointers and solutions are appreciated.

Here is my Python 3.7 based environment:

```
{'IPython': '7.18.1',
 'jedi': '0.17.2',
 'jupyter': '1.0.0',
 'jupyter_core': '4.6.3',
 'jupyter_client': '6.1.7'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunately a ca and mouse battle, IPython used to aggressively explore attribute, which ended up being deactivated because of side effects. (see for example why the `IPCompleter.limit_to__all__` option was added. Though other users come to complain that dynamic attribute don't show up. So it's likely either jedi that look at those attributes. You can try using `c.Completer.use_jedi=False` to check that. If it's jedi, then you have to ask the jedi author, if not then I'm unsure, but it's a delicate balance.

Lazy vs exploratory is really complicated subject in IPython, you might be able to register a custom completer (even for dict keys) that might make it easier to explore without computing, or use async await for make sure only calling `await obj.attr` triggers the computation.